# Another way to pass a value across WebForms

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

If I use a Server.Transfer command with a true value passed for the "PreserveForm" 2nd param's value:

Default.aspx:

```
  Server.Transfer("WebForm1.aspx", True)
```

...I can access the value of the textbox "TextBox1" control on the first page, Default.aspx, from "WebForm1.aspx" as follows:

```
 lblPassedValue.Text = Request.Form("ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1")
```

I know that I can control the way that IDs are generated in Visual Studio 2010, but how about controlling the NAME property?

I would like it to read:

```
 lblPassedValue.Text = Request.Form("TextBox1")
```

I'd also rather use ASP.NET Textbox controls rather than a native HTML textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Transfer("Page.aspx", True)

On Page.aspx:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SenderPage.aspx" %>

Dim Test = CType(Me.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox).Text
```